# how to swap columns in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with three columns: A,B,C.

I want to transpose column A with column B. In other words, insert a copy of Column A between columns B and C, then delete original column A while keeping the one inserted between B and C.

beginning product:[beginning product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muKJG.jpg)

end product: [end product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSMK2.jpg)

I have a script based on a macro recording and I'd like to simply add to the end. It's one thing I haven't been able to do successfully w/ macro recording. Thanks and apologies if you helped on a prior question I had to delete due to errors

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm my understanding of your goal. About `insert Column A between columns B and C, then delete column A`, in this case, you want to delete only the column "A"? Before the script is run, there are the columns "A", "B" and "C" in the sheet as the initial order. After the script was run, the columns are "B" and "C" in order by deleting the column "A". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: sorry for confusion. I want the end product to be three columns in the following order: B,A,C

Comment: Thank you for replying and updated question. From your updated question, I proposed a sample scritp as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move the column "A" between the column "B" and "C" using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, in order to move the column, `moveColumns` is used.

#### Sample script:

Please set the sheet name. When you run this script, at "Sheet1", the column "A" is moved to between the column "B" and "C".

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.moveColumns(sheet.getRange("A1"), 3);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [moveColumns(columnSpec, destinationIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#movecolumnscolumnspec,-destinationindex)

Comment: that works, thanks. I realize though I can't add it to the existing macro without creating a problem so I'll create a new question